# Extract explicit types for all columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
acquisition_date    conductivity    manufacturer    number_bought   price_per_unit  runtime
0   05/25/2008 06:20 PM     115.372339  555-timer   1   9.909869    685.378635
1   07/05/2008 01:58 PM     96.981356   diode   6   11.673483   1020.772530
2   03/25/2008 08:52 AM     103.809491  resistor    7   9.879431    910.086424
3   10/31/2008 05:28 PM     95.805199   transistor  5   10.097940   912.137440
4   03/17/2008 06:58 PM     98.447452   thermistor  0   12.280878   1277.008237
```

where `date` contains a `timestamp` and `manufacturer` contains a `string` data type. I want to go through the dataframe, column by column and create a dictionary whose keys are the data type and whose values are the columns with the given data type.

This is what I am doing now:

```
g = dframe.columns.to_series().groupby(dframe.dtypes).groups
data_types = {k.name: v for k, v in g.items()}
```

and `data_types` looks like this:

```
{'float64': Index(['conductivity', 'price_per_unit', 'runtime'], dtype='object'),
 'int64': Index(['number_bought'], dtype='object'),
 'object': Index(['acquisition_date', 'manufacturer'], dtype='object')}
```

where `acquisition_date` and `manufacturer` are not seen as `timestamp` and `string`, but as `objects`. Is there a way to include `timestamp`, `string` and other possible data types in this dict?

EDIT: Just to make sure I was clear on what I am asking. I want to modify the above code to give me:

```
{'float64': Index(['conductivity', 'price_per_unit', 'runtime'], dtype='object'),
 'int64': Index(['number_bought'], dtype='object'),
 'timestamp': Index(['acquisition_date'], dtype='object'),
 'string': Index(['manufacturer'], dtype='object')}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use df.dtypes to get data type of columns, after that you can create a dictionary with using objects as keys and columns as values

```
df1.acquisition_date = pd.to_datetime(df1.acquisition_date)
dict([(i.name,df1.dtypes[df1.dtypes==i].index) for i in df1.dtypes.unique()])
```

Out:

```
 {'datetime64[ns]': Index(['acquisition_date'], dtype='object'),
 'float64': Index(['conductivity', 'price_per_unit', 'runtime'], dtype='object'),
 'int64': Index(['number_bought'], dtype='object'),
 'object': Index(['manufacturer'], dtype='object')}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. All I want is for my code above to be able to split the "object" class into two different ones "string" and "timestamp" in that dictionary.

Comment: @Qubix is it something like this , you can change the datetime64 key if you want

Answer (score 0):

Two points worth noting:

1. You need to convert a series containing dates explicitly to `datetime` if it currently has `object` dtype.
2. There is no such thing as `string` dtype. Pandas uses `object` dtype to hold arbitrary Python objects.

So you can use `pd.to_datetime`, This assumes that `object` dtype will only contain strings. A proper check of this will have to check each value individually, this is expensive and not advisable. Here's a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-01', '2018-11-30']),
                   'B': [4352.123, 5364.1],
                   'C': [423, 2134],
                   'D': ['SomeString', 'AnotherString'],
                   'E': [653.213, 764.1234],
                   'F': [True, False]})

g = df.columns.to_series().groupby(df.dtypes).groups

data_types = {k.name: v for k, v in g.items()}
```

Result:

```
{'bool': Index(['F'], dtype='object'),
 'datetime64[ns]': Index(['A'], dtype='object'),
 'float64': Index(['B', 'E'], dtype='object'),
 'int64': Index(['C'], dtype='object'),
 'object': Index(['D'], dtype='object')}
```

Note you can also use [`pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
data_types = {i: df.select_dtypes(include=[i]).columns for i in df.dtypes}
```